# Parse Excel file with multi-index in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image: rawdata]

What would be the best way to parse the above Excel file in a Pandas dataframe? The idea would be to be able to update data easily, adding columns, dropping lines. For example, for every origin, I would like to keep only output3. Then for every column (2000, ....,2013) divide it by 2 given a condition (say value > 6000) .

Below is what I tried: first to parse and drop the unnecessary lines, but it's not satisfactory, as I had to rename columns manually. So this doesn't look very optimal as a solution. Any better idea?

```
df = pd.read_excel("myExcel.xlsx",  skiprows=2, sheet_name='1')

cols1 = list(df.columns)
cols1 = [str(x)[:4] for x in cols1]

cols2 = list(df.iloc[0,:])
cols2 = [str(x) for x in cols2]

cols = [x + "_" + y for x,y in zip(cols1,cols2)]
df.columns = cols

df = df.drop(["Unna_nan"], axis =1).rename(columns ={'Time_Origine':'Country','Unna_Output' : 'Series','Unna_Ccy' : 'Unit','2000_nan' : '2000','2001_nan': '2001','2002_nan':'2002','2003_nan' : '2003','2004_nan': '2004','2005_nan' : '2005','2006_nan' : '2006','2007_nan' : '2007','2008_nan' : '2008','2009_nan' : '2009','2010_nan' : '2010','2011_nan': '2011','2012_nan' : '2012','2013_nan':'2013','2014_nan':'2014','2015_nan':'2015','2016_nan':'2016','2017_nan':'2017'})
df.drop(0,inplace=True)
df.drop(df.tail(1).index, inplace=True)

idx = ['Country', 'Series', 'Unit']
df = df.set_index(idx)
df = df.query('Series == "Output3"')
```

Comment: Is possible share your file by dropbox, gdocs, wetransfer or similar? Because hard test your data from picture.

Comment: Where does value come from, when you say you divide the column based on `value > 6000`? Or do you want to check this for each cell?

Comment: I want to check it for every cell

Comment: @jezrael  You can can find the files under <https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OfaYvTG5w8Fe5QDFOG5ibD9X052kPbFR>

Comment: @Crovish - thank you. What is your pandas version?

Comment: I'm using panda 0.22.0

Answer (score 0):

Without having an excel like this I think something like this might work.
In order to only get the rows from output3, you can use the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel("myExcel.xlsx",  skiprows=2, sheet_name='1')
df = df.loc[df['Output'] == 'output3']
```

Now dividing every cell by 2 if the cell value is greater than 6000 by using pandas apply:

```
def foo(bar):
    if bar > 6000:
        return bar / 2
    return bar

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        int(col)  # to check if this column is a year
        df[col] = df[col].apply(foo)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: This won't work because Output is not recognized as a column but more an index.
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: Output

Answer (score 0):

```
#read first 2 rows to MultiIndex nad remove last one
df = pd.read_excel("Excel1.xlsx",  skiprows=2, header=[0,1], skipfooter=1)
print (df)

#create helper DataFrame
cols = df.columns.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
cols.columns=['a','b']
cols['a'] = pd.to_numeric(cols['a'], errors='ignore')
cols['b'] = cols['b'].replace('Unit.1','tmp', regex=False)
#create new column by condition
cols['c'] = np.where(cols['b'].str.startswith('Unnamed'), cols['a'], cols['b'])
print (cols)
       a                    b        c
0   Time              Country  Country
1   Time               Series   Series
2   Time                 Unit     Unit
3   Time                  tmp      tmp
4   2000   Unnamed: 4_level_1     2000
5   2001   Unnamed: 5_level_1     2001
6   2002   Unnamed: 6_level_1     2002
7   2003   Unnamed: 7_level_1     2003
8   2004   Unnamed: 8_level_1     2004
9   2005   Unnamed: 9_level_1     2005
10  2006  Unnamed: 10_level_1     2006
11  2007  Unnamed: 11_level_1     2007
12  2008  Unnamed: 12_level_1     2008
13  2009  Unnamed: 13_level_1     2009
14  2010  Unnamed: 14_level_1     2010
15  2011  Unnamed: 15_level_1     2011
16  2012  Unnamed: 16_level_1     2012
17  2013  Unnamed: 17_level_1     2013
18  2014  Unnamed: 18_level_1     2014
19  2015  Unnamed: 19_level_1     2015
20  2016  Unnamed: 20_level_1     2016
21  2017  Unnamed: 21_level_1     2017
```

---

```
#overwrite columns by column c
df.columns = cols['c'].tolist()
#forward filling missing values
df['Country'] = df['Country'].ffill()
df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1).set_index(['Country','Series','Unit'])
print (df)
```

Comment: I have an error when setting header=[0,1] ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2